# Cleanup function from `useEffect` doesn't get executed

Tags: react-hooks, lifecycle

To my knowledge a component is mount with a state value, on changing that value the component will be unmount and remount with the new state.

This component showes `0` then after 1 second change to `1`, nothing in console. Why doesn't the unmounting of the component with state `0` execute `console.log("unmounting")`?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function HookCounter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => setCount(count + 1), 1000);
    return () => {
      console.log("unmounting");
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>{count}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you didn't understand about `useEffect` hook.
When states are changed, the component will re-render, not re-mount.

In your example, you are passing an empty array as the second argument to `useEffect`, which means that the effect will only run once on mount and once on unmount. The cleanup function will also only run once on unmount.

Thus, when states are changed, you can't reach at your clear up function in `useEffect`.

To learn more, see https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-effect-runs-after-every-re-render

Comment: Hi, [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-cleanup-logic-runs-even-though-my-component-didnt-unmount) says "The cleanup function runs not only during unmount, but before every re-render with changed dependencies", so before re-rendering from `0` to `1`, why does'n it get executed? not even once

Comment: In your case, the dependency array is empty ([]), which means that there are no dependencies that can change and trigger a re-render of the effect. Therefore, the cleanup function does not get executed before re-rendering from 0 to 1, because the effect itself does not re-render. It only runs once on mount and once on unmount